# Cannot link ncurses while compiling vim

Tags: vim, ncurses

I'm trying to compile vim 7.3 in home directory. As a terminal library, I installed ncurses in ~/lib/ncurses/ncurses-5.9 with --with-shared option.

After setting

```
set path = ( ~/lib/ncurses/ncurses-5.9/bin/ $path ) 
setenv LD_LIBRARY_PATH ~/lib/ncurses/ncurses-5.9/lib/:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH
```

I tried to configure vim with

```
./configure --enable-multibyte --prefix=/home/******/apps/vim/vim73
```

or

```
./configure --enable-multibyte --prefix=/home/******/apps/vim/vim73 --with-tlib=ncurses
```

however it failes while searching for ncurses. It seems -lncurses flag is unavailable, and ldconfig did not help.

I do not see what I did wrong... can anybody help me?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

LD_LIBRARY_PATH is used at runtime not compile time to find the correct libraries.  You need to set LDFLAGS or set a configure option to find the ncurses library:

```
env LDFLAGS=-L<PATH TO NCURSES LIB> ./configure ...
```

Comment: `LD_LIBRARY_PATH is used at runtime not compile time to find the correct libraries`. This is the part I'm confused. Sometimes the program compiles and won't run due to this kind of error. How does that work? You compile a program to an executable and it should include everything you need to run it, right? Why would it need a library at runtime?

Answer (score 11):

Install the `ncurses-devel` package

```
$ yum install ncurses-devel
```

Then try again:

```
$ ./configure <your options>
```

Answer (score 3):

In the vim git directory, after reading from command line `./configure --help`, what I did was:

```
./configure --with-local-dir=PATH
```

where PATH is the path to the ncurses directory (with all its libraries). Like in my case it was:

```
./configure --with-local-dir=/opt/ncurses
```

This seemed to give no error about not finding ncurses library. And the installation went properly.