# Raspbian building ncurses and vim from source

Tags: linux, vim, raspbian, raspberry-pi3, ncurses

I don't have an internet connection and won't for at least a few weeks. I had to download a minimal version of Raspbian which vim isn't included by default. Without internet access on my Pi I'm not able to use the package manager.

I downloaded ncurses 6.0 from https://ftp.gnu.org/pub/gnu/ncurses/ncurses-6.0.tar.gz and installed it to `/opt/ncurses`. In order to get it to build I had to `export CPPFLAGS="-P"` before running configure.

Next I grabbed vim 8.0 from ftp://ftp.vim.org/pub/vim/unix/vim-8.0.tar.bz2. When I try to run `./configure` with the argument `with-tlib=ncurses` it fails with the message:

```
checking --with-tlib argument... ncurses
checking for linking with ncurses library... configure: error: FAILED
```

Looking in `/opt/ncurses/lib` I notice the development libraries aren't there.

```
pi@raspberrypi:/opt/ncurses/lib $ ls -l
total 7300
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   92482 Nov 29 06:09 libform.a
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 1138744 Nov 29 06:09 libform_g.a
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   49122 Nov 29 06:09 libmenu.a
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  653288 Nov 29 06:09 libmenu_g.a
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  464600 Nov 29 06:09 libncurses.a
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  135894 Nov 29 06:09 libncurses++.a
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 4080812 Nov 29 06:09 libncurses_g.a
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  498190 Nov 29 06:09 libncurses++_g.a
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   20190 Nov 29 06:09 libpanel.a
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  320340 Nov 29 06:09 libpanel_g.a
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root      17 Nov 29 06:09 terminfo -> ../share/terminfo
```

Comparing this to what's in the `libncurses5-dev` (https://packages.ubuntu.com/trusty/arm64/libncurses5-dev/filelist) I can see the shared libraries here.

I haven't had to do this before manually so to be honest I'm not even sure if I'm on the right path. Should I have the shared libraries from the build or would I need to obtain them separately?

Comment: I just realised when I configured ncurses that I forgot the option `--with-shared`. I'll try with this, perhaps this creates the libraries I need.

Comment: Could it be a search-path issue?  Maybe you need to get `/opt/ncurses/lib` into `$LD_LIBRARY_PATH` for `configure`.

Comment: Also, if all you need is a working vim, couldn't you download that particular dpkg from the web and use that rather than building from source?

Comment: I've rebuilt the libraries and tried `export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/opt/ncurses/lib` before I get the same error message. Perhaps DPKG would be a better choice, though I'm not sure where to find it. Every article I look for says just grab it from the repository which I can't do.

Comment: What is your `configure` command?

Comment: @jww: for vim `./configure --prefix=/usr/local --without-x --disable-nls --enable-gui=no --enable-multibyte --enable-rubyinterp --enable-luainterp --enable-pythoninterp --with-python-config-dir=$HOME/lib/python2.7/config     --with-features=huge --with-tlib=ncurses`. 

for ncurses: `./configure --prefix=/opt/ncurses --with-shared --without-normal --without-debug --enable-pc-files`

Comment: An internet connection is required to install the missing dependencies through `sudo apt build-dep ncurses`.

Comment: @GAD3R I managed to get it working. ncurses wasn't the issue, I didn't configure it to build the shared libraries nor do I have the ncurses library directory on `LDPATH`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Originally I forgot the flag `--with-shared` during the configuration for ncurses. Because I also installed ncurses to `/opt/ncurses` I needed to first `export LDPATH=-L/opt/ncurses/lib` and then configure vim. [image]

I got the hint for `LDPATH` from [Cannot link ncurses while compiling vim](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8834438/cannot-link-ncurses-while-compiling-vim/15965906).